# how to create a fixed scrolling sidebar in bootstrap theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap theme which offer a option of fix left navigation bar with a separate scroll bar on the navigation, but that option activates only when i select it from settings and ON the fix sidebar....what if i want the fix sidebar by default when the page loads

I have checked the CSS and Javascript of the theme by inspect element in chrome and tried applying the same to my code but not working the way i want.

This is the code i found :

```
<div class="setings-item">

    <span>
        Fixed sidebar
    </span>

    <div class="switch">
        <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fixedsidebar" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="fixedsidebar">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="fixedsidebar">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    // Enable/disable fixed sidebar
$('#fixedsidebar').click(function () {
    if ($('#fixedsidebar').is(':checked')) {
        $("body").addClass('fixed-sidebar');
        $('.sidebar-collapse').slimScroll({
            height: 'auto',
            railOpacity: 0.9,
        });
    } else {
        $('.sidebar-collapse').slimscroll({destroy: true});
        $('.sidebar-collapse').attr('style', '');
        $("body").removeClass('fixed-sidebar');
    }
});
```

Comment: This might be something you need to do with a cookie.

Comment: can you give us the css to this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pm4awywf/
I've created fiddle for you. Please continue with the css.

Comment: @JanakaDombawela This css i have found: 

body:not(.fixed-sidebar).mini-navbar .nav li:hover > .nav-second-level,
.mini-navbar .nav li:focus > .nav-second-level {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: auto;
}

body.fixed-sidebar .navbar-static-side {
  position: fixed;
  width: 220px;
  z-index: 101;
  height: 100%;
}

body.body-small.fixed-sidebar.mini-navbar .navbar-static-side {
  width: 220px;
}
.fixed-sidebar.mini-navbar .nav li:focus > .nav-second-level {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}